# Does not work changing a value from dataframe in R

Tags: r, web-scraping

I am kind of new to R and the web scraping world. I really can't figure out why `df[df == "x"]` does not work in this situation:

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

# Step 1: Read URL
htmlpage <- read_html("http://www.bmbets.com/football/england/premier-league/")

# Step 2: Extract info from web
Data <- htmlpage %>%
  html_nodes("table") %>%
  html_table()

#Step 3: Subset correct table
Data <- Data[[3]]

# Step 4: Change column names
colnames(Data) <- c("Date", "Venue", "V1", "V2", "V3", "Payout", "B")

# Step 5: Select columns
Data <- select(Data, 1:5)

# Step 6: Separate 'Venue' column with tidyr package
Data <- Data %>%
  separate(Venue, into = c("Home", "Away"), sep = "\\-", extra = "merge")

# Step 7: Change team name
Data[Data == "Leicester City"] <- "Leicester"

tbl_df(Data)
```

And this is the result:

```
                        Date               Home            Away    V1    V2    V3
                       (chr)              (chr)           (chr) (dbl) (chr) (dbl)
1                      12:45   West Ham United       Sunderland  1.81  3.61  4.41
2                      15:00    Leicester City     Norwich City  1.49  4.27  6.60
3                      15:00       Southampton          Chelsea  2.59  3.21  2.77
```

"Leicester City" team does not change! Why?

'Data' object is a data.frame, Home and Away fields are 'chr'...I thought the problem was related to tidyr package, but even if I just try to change a team name in step #3 it does not work!

Any ideas?

Comment: Because it is `"Leicester City "`, not `"Leicester City"`. You can simply see it with `Data[2,2]`.

Comment: Before replacing, I'd suggest to trim the strings. After the `separate` part, `Data[,2:3]<-lapply(Data[,2:3],trimws)` will remove any leading/trailing white space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the comments by Pascal and nicola,

```
Data[,c("Home", "Away")] <- sapply(Data[,c("Home", "Away")],trimws)
Data[Data == "Leicester City"] <- "Leicester"
tbl_df(Data)
```

Comment: I guess the problem is wider than this "simple" replacement.

Comment: Thanks. I was missing a "]"

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out in the comments, the problem is due to leading and trailing whitespaces. The comments by @Pascal and @nicola also provide a good solution.

If these whitespace characters don't bother you and if you simply want to replace "Leicester City" with "Leicester" in your data frame, an alternative consists in using `sub()` or `gsub()` instead of searching for exact identities. One such possibility would be:

```
Data[] <- sapply(Data, function(x) sub("Leicester City", "Leicester", x))
#> head(Data)
#   Date             Home            Away   V1   V2   V3
#1 12:45 West Ham United       Sunderland 1.81 3.61 4.41
#2 15:00       Leicester     Norwich City 1.49 4.27 6.61
#3 15:00     Southampton          Chelsea  2.6 3.21 2.77
#4 15:00      Stoke City      Aston Villa 1.64 3.63 5.78
#5 15:00         Watford      Bournemouth 2.35 3.28 3.04
#6 17:30   West Bromwich   Crystal Palace 2.58 3.12 2.86
```